# Call once in Update() without boolean condition

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

This question is related to Unity3D C# as well as AppGameKit C++.

Is it advisable to use boolean condition to call a function/statements once as shown in the example below?

Unity3D C#

```
bool _call = false;

void Update()
{
  if (!_call)
    {
      call = true;
      // statements
    }
}
```

AGK C++

```
bool _call = false;

void app::Loop(void)
{
  if (!_call)
    {
      _call = true;
      // statements
    }
}
```

I'm asking this because of the following reasons:

1. I've read in both Unity as well as AGK forums that using if-else / switch conditions should be as minimal as possible in Update() function which updates each frame.
2. I'm curious if there is any other way it is possible to have statements/functions called just once while they are being called in the Update() function. If not, can I make the program go back to Start() / Begin() section of the program while in the middle of the Update() / Loop() function to have the functions/statements to get called there, once.

Comment: What exactly is `_call` doing? That's a very non-descriptive and ambiguous name.

Comment: _"that using **if-else** / switch conditions should be as minimal as possible"_  - I think you mean **if (...) else if**.  http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/337248/using-else-if.html   `if () else` would be too limiting.  And it's in general, not just for `Update()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Having a single boolean conditional each frame isn't going to make much of a difference to performance.  That said, it's good practice to keep logic to a minimum so doing something like this would require a very good reason in terms of design.

2) Execution of a script can be restarted.  Check out this link: [OnEnable, Awake, Start order](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/217941/onenable-awake-start-order.html)
and this link here: [Behaviour.enabled](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Behaviour-enabled.html)

Answer (score 0):

1) I am using this in my game and I have no problem so I do not see why wouldn't this be possible in your game

2) You can not make program go to the Start() it is called once at the beginning of the screen that uses that script.

Comment: This is very much possible in my game too, I'm simply wondering if there is a better (maybe more optimized) way of doing this instead of having an if-else condition. I'm looking for a better solution, that's all.